# how to restrict jdk api version in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using jdk1.6 in my eclipse build path. But i want to restrict the eclipse to show only those methods that is supported in jdk1.4.2. Is there anyway to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Project properties -> Java build path -> Libraries tab.
Select your JDK/JRE, click Edit
Select "Execution environment", Select J2SE-1.4, click Finish, click OK

You might also want to set your JDK compliance level to 1.4, that's in Java Compiler in either project or workspace settings.