# Force Eclipse use only Java 1.4

Tags: java, eclipse

Locally I need to code against Java 1.4.

I tried the suggestion in this post
[how to restrict jdk api version in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100713/how-to-restrict-jdk-api-version-in-eclipse)

however Eclipse still provides code completion for `String.contains` which is only available in Java 1.5 Nor did it provide the Red X error marker.

How can I get Eclipse to only provide code completion for Java 1.4 Classes and Methods and warn me with the Red X that I can't use something above version 1.4?

Comment: Did you set compilation level? It should be set to 1.4 as well. I guess you just added JRE.

Comment: I do have the compiler comliance level set to 1.4.  But installed on my PC is 1.6.  As ajozwik pointed out I probably need to have JDK 1.4 installed on my PC so when coding locally I get the RED X if the Class is out of scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install java version 1.4.2 on your computer and define jre 1.4.2. It is not enough to set compilance with 1.4, because you still see 1.5 api

Comment: This is sounding right. IT keeps our PC right up to date with JDK but on our webserver they still have 1.4

Comment: In eclipse preference-> java -> installed jre and add jdk 1.4. Next go to Execution environment and choose J2SE-1.4 and check jdk 1.4

Comment: Isn't this the way it is described in the link in my Question? But without actually downloading jdk 1.4? Right now I have selected J2SE-1.4 (jdk1.6.0_22) If I download 1.4 will it read J2SE-1.4 (jdk1.4.2) ?  I thought the point of the execution environment was to be able to downgrade the version without having to actually download and install that version.

Comment: rt.jar in normal library. If it contains new methods - eclipse see it. It is not difference between commons-lang.jar and rt.jar for eclipse (and java compiler)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually have JDK 1.4 installed, Eclipse's compiler can't know that things like String.contains() weren't in that version. Specifying the Execution Environment just tells it that it can only do Java 1.4 compatible compilation, but things like methods in the String class are part of the library (classes.jar), not inherent to the Java language level. So if all you have is later JDKs, the compiler sees String.contains() in classes.jar and hence compiles your code against it.

So, install JDK 1.4 and then set it up in the Installed JREs section of Preferences; also make sure it is set as the default for the 1.4 Execution Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and go to Properties.  Check the Java Compiler options to make sure the jdk compliance is with 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Properties -> Java Compiler and make sure all of your JDK compliance settings are at 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Go to project settings --> Java compiler, uncheck the default code compliance and select the 1.4.

Comment: This won't work if all that is installed are later JDKs. The compiler doesn't know what was in each version of the libraries (classes.jar).

Answer (score 0):

You can force eclipse to use any previous java version following these steps:

**Steps**

1. **Right click project** and open properties clicking **Properties** option.
2. Select **Java Compiler** option.
3. In **JDK Compliance** category uncheck **Use Compliance from execution ...** option
4. Now select desired java version (1.4) in **Compiler compliance level:** option
5. And click **OK**

**Result**

Now eclipse will use desired previous version (say 1.4) without installing it explicitly even if you have 1.7 or 8.0 installed/configured.

Answer (score 0):

You have two option :
First : Go to project settings --> Java compiler, uncheck the default code compliance and select the 1.4.
Second : downgrad your project java version to 1.4 by install and maintain alternative java versions in your case its 1.5 and 1.4.

I prefer send because unless you not able run the project with even error.